# How to receive Response from API in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I have a basic form that makes a **POST** request to my API(localhost:7000). The API receives my REQUEST, it inserts a new record to my database and all works fine.

Now, I want to receive a response in my Website (localhost:5000) or any custom message given from the API, so that I can do basic *if-else* stuff.
Although, Im sending **res.sendStatus(200)** from my API but it redirects my Website to a blank page with the **"OK"** message

***POST route of the API***

[image: POST route of the API]

***Website rendering file***

[image]

Comment: instead of sendstatus. try
res.json({success:true,data:results})

Comment: but I dont want to send any data. I just want to send a simple message. 
Secondly, how and where will I access that message in my web?

Comment: Your message will be displayed in where you get OK message.
If you dont want any data you can simply use custom data
res.json({sucess:true,data:"Query Successfully Executed"})

Comment: I want to redirect to some URL if get a certain response. I can receive the JSON but I dont want to do that.

Comment: Can I ask you which framework are you using? like angular,react,vue,Jquery?

Comment: When you hit the API, the response will come in json fomat.
you do like this.
if(data.sucesss) dosometing;

Comment: Using ExpressJS. Making request from a simple HTML <form>

Comment: Okay, but on which route I shall access my json? I only have one route (GET) and its rendering my template

Comment: You probably want a flash message. Check out this tutorial: https://scotch.io/courses/create-a-crud-app-with-node-and-mongodb/showing-success-messages - Also, please don't send code as images. See [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) to understand why. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can give back a JSON response

```
res.json({
”message":”some message" 
})
```

You can access this message using Javascript in front end.

```
const data = { username: 'example' };

fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then((response) => { 
if(response.message){
dosomething()
 }
 })
.catch((error) => {
console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: Use javascript fetch() to POST. You will get the response message in a promise or callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: After the POST request, Im getting this JSON object on my web page, I dont want that, I want to create a check. Example: if (message=="Success"){doSomething();}

Comment: Using fetch() method to POST wont allow me to POST from my HTML <form/> right?

Comment: Yes, You have to do preventDefault() and then use fetch()

Comment: Your code is not formatted properly and has incorrect quotes which won't compile...

Comment: Just an example (I typed in mobile) don't copy paste. Write your own code.